# When do we use “adept in” and “adept at”?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, prepositions, adjectives

I was reading a chapter on choosing the appropriate preposition and found there are two different uses of *adept* with two different prepositions, namely “in” and “at”.

The examples that were given did not help me to understand the difference well.

Comment: I think you're quite right. Even finding the more common pairing on Google ('adept in fishing', say) doesn't guarantee the best answer, and dictionaries below OED level seem of little use. The few Google Ngram pairs I've checked suggest choices I'd feel happier with.

Comment: Adept in a field.  Adept at a skill.

Answer (score 7):

In short popularity wise two uses can be discerned:

> Adept at **word ending in -ing**; E.g. I am adept at answering.
>
> Adept in **the *noun* of whatever**; E.g. I am adept in the art of answering.

---

A dive into the digitized google corpus reveals some patterns:

- adept in **verb(ing)** [results in 5k  hits](http://googlebooks.byu.edu/?c=us&q=49476514)
- adept at **verb(ing)** [results in 55k hits](http://googlebooks.byu.edu/?c=us&q=49476512)

Therefore **at** is widely more common when followed by such a verb.

Adept in/at, followed by **the noun of**, the result is different.

- adept in **the noun of** [results in 4.7k hits](http://googlebooks.byu.edu/?c=us&q=49476643)
- adept at **the noun of** [results in meager 900 hits](http://googlebooks.byu.edu/?c=us&q=49476640)

---

After these two that are pretty clear I looked at **adept at/in noun** and here it gets murkier. On the first look **at** seems to be winning [with 6.3k hits](http://googlebooks.byu.edu/?c=us&q=49476708) versus [2k hits](http://googlebooks.byu.edu/?c=us&q=49476717) for **in**. However a lot of those are nominalized verbs ending on -ing (7 out of the top 10). The other three are **self** as used in self-whatever (management, study...), **problem** in what looks to exclusively *problem solving* and finally **mathematics.** The last also claims the top three spot in the **adept in** search. That leaves 158 'at' vs 110 'in' for mathematics. Politics is 95 'at' to 66 'in'. Music however '137' in to just 50 'at'.

The only obvious pattern seems that noun or verb, if the word ends on -ing use **adept at**.

---

On a speculative note it might be shifting towards **adept at noun**, since a lot of entries in the *adept in noun* results are more obscure, old or fantasy based (alchemy, astrology, occult, sorcery, necromancy, woodcraft), they also seem more negative over all (deceit, crime, villainy, intrigue, politics ;)).

Answer (score 0):

Well, shooting from the hip here, I'd guess that it should sound correct, but that answer is of no help to someone looking for a rule or a non-native English speaker.
I'll say that you'd use **in** when talking about a general skill and **at** when being more specific. Some examples which sound right to my ear:

He's adept **at** puzzle=making.
She's adept **in** the field of study regarding puzzle-making.

He's adept **at** making others look foolish.
She's adept **in** the art of making her adversaries look foolish.

Comment: While I think there's an element of truth in what you say, it's worse suggesting a rule that doesn't really work than making a less precise claim. If you compare Google hits for "adept in dancing" and "adept at dancing", you'll see they are approximately equal. Also, 'adept in needlework' and 'adept at needlework' give roughly similar results. 'Adept in sports' and 'adept at sports' are neck-and-neck. / Answers of the 'shooting-from-the-hip' variety are never exactly appreciated on ELU.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth It sounds to me like 2.5 million people out there are wrong. I do freelance copywriting and proofreading for extra cash and I would *definitely* at least suggest that "adept at the art of" be changed. It just sounds bad.

Comment: I think you make a valid point; the downvote isn't mine (though I'd guess it's for an unsupported answer). I've tried to find at least a partial pattern, linking say 'adept in' to 'skilled in' (followed by more 'verby' ing-forms, fields rather than particulars) and 'adept at' to 'good at', but results I wouldn't expect keep appearing in Google data. 'Skilled in chess' is the favoured form (19 / 20 relevant hits in the first two pages of 30 000 hits). 'Adept in fishing' seems to outperform the at-version.

Comment: [These two Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=adept+in+the+art+of%2Cadept+at+the+art+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadept%20in%20the%20art%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadept%20at%20the%20art%20of%3B%2Cc0) provide more substantial evidence (than raw Google data) that 'adept at the art of' is becoming as acceptable as 'adept in the art of'. I'm with you in preferring the latter, but am anti-prescriptivist enough not to consider the alternative incorrect.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth -- I never said that anything was "incorrect," I was going with what "sounds right to my ear." Also, by the by, the day you find me using Google Ngrams to determine whether a sentence sounds good or not is the day you'll find me dead at my desk, a letter opener protruding from my lifeless chest. :)

Comment: The trouble is that 'sounds correct to my ear' is subjective (even from a pro copywriter) and thus (unless supported by references) unsuitable for an 'answer' on ELU. It would make a fine 'comment'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth and yet the answer is *inherently* subjective. Both phrases were still in wide use as of the year 2000, per Google's Ngram. A ratio of approximately 80 to 54, even, the closest in history. Substantiated or not, my answer is my educated opinion.

Comment: That's not a correct rejoinder to the previous comment, as you're well aware.

Comment: *a letter opener protruding from my lifeless chest* I wouldn't suspect the Ngram viewer. More likely an irate client who relied on what sounded "right" to your ear. You know how touchy those clients can be. (Does *alright* look good to you?)

Comment: @deadrat I was suggesting that I would sooner kill myself than have Google Ngrams dictate how I write.

Comment: Were you now? Do I have to mark these kinds of comments as facetious? Because I will. It just takes the fun out of it for me. And GooGrams doesn't tell you how to write. It tells you how other people write.